# what kind of code i should use in fullCalendar to call the start time and end time that i just store in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fullcalendar, local-storage

Does anyone know what kind of code i should use in fullCalendar to call the start time and end time that i just store in localstorage?

I did try this code:

`start: new Date(datefrom[x]). getTime(timefrom[x]),
end: new Date(dateto[x]). getTime(timeto[x]),` but doesn't work. The date is working though but not the time.

Comment: how to store and get it in/from the `localStorage` ?

Comment: get it from localstorage into fullcalendar so that the calendar may identify for each of my event time

Comment: can you share the code which you have used for `store/get` it from `localStorage` ?